# Rails 3, Paperclip and uploading image from remote url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, paperclip

I wrote simple code which takes url of an image, and uploads resized version of it to Amazon S3 storage. Code looks like this:

```
  attr_accessor :profile_image_url

  has_attached_file :avatar, 
    :default_url => "/system/avatars/:style_default.png",
    :styles => { 
      :original => "128x128#",
      :thumb => "48x48#"
    },
    :storage => :s3, 
    :s3_credentials => "#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/s3.yml",
    :path => "/avatars/:id/:style.:extension"

  before_validation :download_profile_pic
...

  def download_profile_pic
    begin
      io = open(URI.parse(self.profile_image_url))
      def io.original_filename; base_uri.path.split('/').last; end
      self.avatar = io.original_filename.blank? ? nil : io  
    rescue Timeout::Error
      self.avatar = nil
    rescue OpenURI::Error => e
      self.avatar = nil
    end
  end
```

It works, but the images are uploaded in a very low quality. What could be a problem?

Comment: your original image will become  "128x128" px , It's your intent ? define low quality, in compression rate ?

Comment: this is correct - my original image dimensions are "128x128", and I have tried defining quality by doing smth like this :style=>{:thumb=>{:quality=>100,...}} and it still returned same result

Comment: Hey, this works great!  I was wondering, can you please explain the 'def io.original_filename; base_uri.path.split('/').last; end' line a bit?  Are you declaring a function here? and what is the semi-colon for?

Comment: @TenJack this statement "def io.original_filename; base_uri.path.split('/').last; end", opens "io" object, inserts new method to it called "original_filename", this is done only when method "download_profile_pic" is executed. Semicolons can be used to have multiple lines of code in one line (if that makes sense(in code above same stuff could have been written in 3 lines)). Also I want to note that this code is not mine, some smart dude wrote it, and I just slightly modified it (as much as I remember).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the issue is the geometry string on your main image size, try changing:

```
:styles => { 
  :original => "128x128#",
  :thumb => "48x48#"
},
```

to

```
:styles => { 
  :original => "128x128>",
  :thumb => "48x48#"
},
```

Which should only resize/transform the image if the dimensions are too large.